Sample size calculation for generalized linear mixed models - variance assumption for the random effect
Introduction
I would like to perform a sample size calculation for the Poisson generalized linear mixed model.
I will leave out irrelevant details, I need to deal with clustered data and the model has the following form (3 categorical variables with 2 categories each).
$$\log (\mathbb{E}(Y_{ij}|X)) = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{1,ij} + \beta_2X_{2,ij} + \beta_3X_{3,ij} + \gamma_j,$$
where $\gamma_j \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_j^2)$ and $j$ corresponds to one of the clusters. The parameter $\beta_1$ is of my primary interest and I know that there should be around 8-12 clusters in my experiment.
I have data from a previous experiment so I could find reasonable assumptions and estimates for the parameters in the model. However, what I am missing here is assumptions about the covariance structure because the previous experiment had a different design with no clustering so the Poisson GLM without random effects was fitted.
Question
Can I somehow make use of the model without random effects used in the previous experiment and make reasonable (possibly conservative) assumptions about the variance before running simulations? 
Any input appreciated. Thanks.

"Can I somehow make use of the model without random effects used in the previous experiment and make reasonable (possibly conservative) assumptions about the variance before running simulations?" - sounds reasonable to me. That's basically what a power analysis is anyway, making a "best guess" of parameters (which might be off previous data) and then seeing if you study design is adequate to detect it

@AlexJ The question is about how to elicit information about the variance from the previous experiment as it did not account for clustering.

OK. That sentence wasn't clear to me, but I understand now. In the previous experiment, you had no information about clusters though, correct?

@AlexJ That's right. There is no information about clustering. I want to know if it's possible to elicit information about the variance of random intercept from that pilot data.

Unfortunately, not that I can think of. I can only suggest you just run your sample size calculations under a range of potential values (e.g. a "best case", "worst case", "middle ground").
